# download the repositories in maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have an application (Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations) , integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration. I just added a couple of repositories **OSGEO GeoTools repo** & **Hibernate Spatial repo** in order to have access to **org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType** type. I clean and install the maven project but the jar is not installed.

- hibernate-spatial 5.0.5 is not be compatible with the version of hibernate I am using 4.3.2.
- versions available in maven central are the version starting from version

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
            xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <groupId>fr.telecom.device</groupId>
            <artifactId>telecomDevices</artifactId>
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <name>telecomDevices</name>

            <properties> 
                <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
                <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
                <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
                <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
                <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>
                <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
                <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
                <dbunit.version>2.2</dbunit.version>
            </properties>
```

> dependency section

```
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Spring -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Hibernate -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!--  dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
                </dependency-->

                <!-- jsr303 validation -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- MySQL -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${mysql.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Gson-->
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- apache commons --> 
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                     <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                     <version>3.4</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Joda-Time -->      
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                    <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->         
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
                    <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>


                <!-- Testing dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                    <version>${testng.version}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                    <version>${mockito.version}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <version>${h2.version}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>dbunit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
                    <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                  <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
                  <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                  <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
                  <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
                 </repository>
            </repositories>
     </project>
```

Comment: You've added the repositories, but I don't see any place where you've actually added the jars as dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch your dependency on hibernate-spatial. You commented it. Here is it:

```
 <!--  dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency-->
```

Just remove a chars after/before <> ;) And use correct version:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
     <version>4.X.X</version>
</dependency>
```

On [their pages](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/) you can see this:
Hibernate Spatial version 4.3 is compatible with Hibernate 4.3.x only
Hibernate Spatial version 4.0 is compatible with Hibernate 4.x only

Comment: hibernate-spatial 5.0.5 is not be compatible with the version of hibernate I am  using 4.3.2.

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada well, do you think that then, I dunno, maybe uncommenting the dependency _and_ changing the version number would work? Just a wild stab in the dark here :)

Comment: versions available in maven central are the version starting from version

Comment: If you are using Hibernate 4, then change version of spatial to 4.3 :)

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada that wasn't obvious from your question. You just said "it won't download the jar" and the obvious answer to that is "well you've commented out your dependency". Also: if this particular library is not available for the version of Hibernate you're using, what did you _expect_ would happen? It sounds like you should update/edit your question to make it more clear what exactly it is you want to achieve here,